# How can I get datepicker instances of different sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I got a datepicker set up for my main page and now I wanna set it up for some of my other stuff. The problem is that I need it smaller than what I'm using on the main page. Is there a way to have different sizes for different instances of the datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI uses CSS to style all of it's widgets, and those are typically stored in a CSS file as theme. Depending on the theme you're using it may or may not be possible.

If the theme you're using uses `ems` or `%` for the `width` and `font-size`, then you could easily create a new style that would alter the look of all of its children.

For example:

```
.someClassNotOnTheMainPage .datepicker {
   font-size:.75em;
   ...
}
```

If you're looking for a pure Javascript solution or an option to pass to the datepicker widget, unfortunately, there isn't one.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I should've thought about it but aparently my brain decided to forget how CSS works.

Answer (score 1):

You can design and load a different **css** than the default jQueryUI theme. Although the themes usually [have the same size](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) for the calendar, you can choose to personalize this feature to your needs.